# Change View on only one Tab in Tabbar-Application (Landscape-Portrait)?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, landscape

How can I change the view when rotating the iphone (change nib's).
But it should only happens in one single tab!
I tried it with:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
 LandscapeViewController *viewController = [[LandscapeViewController alloc]
             initWithNibName:@"LandscapeView" bundle:nil];
 self.landscapeViewController = viewController;
 [viewController release];

 [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
             name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil]; }

- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(updateLandscapeView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}

- (void)updateLandscapeView
{
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation) && !isShowingLandscapeView)
 {
        [self presentModalViewController:self.landscapeViewController animated:YES];
        isShowingLandscapeView = YES;
    }
 else if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait && isShowingLandscapeView)
 {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
    }    
}
```

But then the Landscape-View appears in all Tabs. (When this code is loaded once).
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tanks for your comments!
I found a workaround:

```
//Remove Observer if not in Landscape
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    if (isShowingLandscapeView == NO) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    }   
}

//Add Observer if not in Landscape
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if (isShowingLandscapeView == NO) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is your view controller is receiving the `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` notification whenever the rotation changes, whether or not it is being displayed.  Instead try using the built-in methods of `UIViewController` that are meant for responding to rotations.

http://tinyurl.com/ycb8of2

Answer (score 0):

This is from Apple's Docs (View Controller Programming Guide):

> Tab Bar Controllers and View Rotation
>
> Tab bar controllers support a portrait
>   orientation by default and do not
>   rotate to a landscape orientation
>   unless all of the root view
>   controllers support such an
>   orientation. When a device orientation
>   change occurs, the tab bar controller
>   queries its array of view controllers.
>   If any one of them does not support
>   the orientation, the tab bar
>   controller does not change its
>   orientation.

So, I'm not sure that the Tab Bar Controller is designed to rotate just for a single view.